# Tempo de execução em C

Tags: c, time

Gostaria de pegar o tempo de execução em milisegundos de uma aplicação, fiz o seguinte algorítmo.

```
double writingFS(char* Filepath, char* PenDrivepath, clock_t* thput) {
clock_t t1, t2;
long size = 0;
unsigned char buff[PAGE_SIZE];

FILE* fs_file = fopen(PenDrivepath, "w+");
assert(fs_file != NULL);

setbuf(fs_file,NULL);


int fdrand = open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY);

int i;
int tam = (10 * 1000000)/ PAGE_SIZE;

t1 = clock();


for (i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
    read(fdrand, buff, PAGE_SIZE);
    fwrite(buff, 1, PAGE_SIZE, fs_file); 
}

fflush(fs_file);
t2 = clock();


double diff =( (double)(t2 - t1) / (((double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC)/1000)  );


*thput = (clock_t)(size / (diff/1000.0));


fclose(fs_file);
close(fdrand);

return diff;
```

O tempo que está sendo retornado gira em torno de 351ms, mas o tempo de rodagem do algorítmo gira em torno de 3sec (3000ms). O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que não é necessário fazer a divisão CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000.
Note que você tem a duração do pedaço de código que te interessa em diff.
Para conseguir o tempo, basta fazer a regra de 3 seguinte

1s    = CLOCKS_PER_SEC

tempo = diff

logo: tempo = diff/CLOCKS_PER_SEC e não diff/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000), como você fez.